# API JSON in Latex

Tags: luatex, urls, datatool, json

I want to know if it's possible to get data from a website using api json in a document .tex

I want to do this without luatex because the idea is compile online with the sharelatex website, that does't support luatex.

Best regards

Comment: yes, but I understand that he just uses luacode package to generate data, but not gettting data from a url

Comment: Sharelatex _does_ support luatex. You can select which compiler to use in the project settings. However, I doubt it will let your document to make socket connections (I don't even think that lualatex implements the socket api, but of course much less pure latex could do that)

Comment: You can do it without LuaTeX, I'm sure, because you can use any external tool you like. But you are not going to be able to do it using an online compilation service worth its salt, because any sane service will prohibit users from running external stuff. You'd need to enable shell escape and no sane webmaster is going to let you do that on their server. To put this another way: if ShareLaTeX did let you do this, that would be a reason to run away from that service *fast* because it would mean it was in the hands of idiots. Fortunately, I'm sure they aren't idiots as uptime exceeds 30 secs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend against trying to import data directly into LaTeX from a REST/JSON API. This would in any case require outside tools as LaTeX cannot open network connections. I'd suggest to use a language like Python or Ruby to query the API and to transform the JSON data into something that is easier to process with LaTeX.

A great tool for transforming JSON data is [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) - I'm using it to trim down JSON data to the bits that I need in a document in combination with Curl to retrieve the data from a REST API.

Here is code using Curl, jq, and the API from above. It emits

```
\geo{37.4220352}%
     {-122.0841244}
```

which would be easy to parse in LaTeX by creating a command `\geo`.

```
#! /bin/sh

URL="http://216.58.210.138/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false"

curl -s "$URL" | jq -r '"
\\geo{\(.results[0].geometry.location.lat)}%
     {\(.results[0].geometry.location.lng)}
"'
```

Answer (score 7):

As I hinted in a comment, even if Sharelatex allows to use lualatex as compiler for your documents, it does not allow network connections from luatex code. I performed the following test:

1. Wrote the following testing file, which attempts a connection to Google Geocoding API to get a JSON containing geocoding information about the location "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA". Then, it uses `lualibs` to convert that JSON into lua tables, and then the `"lat"` and `"lng"` of the geolocation components are printed in the document.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{luacode}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{luacode}
   local http = require("socket.http")
   require("lualibs.lua")

   r, c, h = http.request ("http://216.58.210.138/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false")

   if r then
      local s =  utilities.json.tolua(r)
      tex.print("Success! $\\to$ (")
      tex.print(tostring(s["results"][1]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]), ", ")
      tex.print(tostring(s["results"][1]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]), ")")
   else
      tex.print("ERROR: ")
      tex.print(c)
   end
   \end{luacode}
   \end{document}
   ```

   When run locally, this works and produces a document containing:

   [image: Successful result]
2. Upload above code to Sharelatex, and ensured that lualatex compiler was in use (as shown in next screenshot)

   [image: Sharelatex settings]
3. Compiled this example in Sharelatex, but got a document showing an error:

   [image: Network error]

So, as expected, Sharelatex does not allow network connections.

Comment: FYI, I tried the same test in Overleaf (another online latex engine), with the same unsuccessful result.